# Expected height of a random binary tree

Tags: binary-tree

I read in *introduction to algorithms* that it is not clear what the expected height of a randomized binary tree is. Here the "randomized binary tree" meant a tree randomly contructed by randomly inserting and deleting nodes. May I ask what is the essential difficulty for this problem? The original wording is:

"
Unfortunately, little is known about the average height of a binary search tree
when both insertion and deletion are used to create it." (Chapter 12)

All answers are welcome (my CS level is really low)

Comment: Every insertion *may* increase the depth by 1. Some deletions *may* decrease it by 1. For example, a sequence of 255 insertions (assuming there was no root node to begin with) could result in an 8-level perfectly filled tree. Or it could result in a 255-deep left-child-only tree. Or anything in between. Tossing deletions in the process as well just makes the outcome less clear.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/877084/25216