# BST height in python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I have written a class called Node with certain functions to create a binary search tree. All of the functions work correctly except the function height() that is supposed to calculate the height of the BST. It returns a very small number compared to what I was expecting it too given that I haven't balanced the tree. The number I was expecting was close to N where N is the amount of numbers I have entered in the tree. Here is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random

class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, data):

        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data

    def insert(self, data):

        if self.data:
            if data < self.data:
                if self.left is None:
                    self.left = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.left.insert(data)
            elif data > self.data:
                if self.right is None:
                    self.right = Node(data)
                else:
                    self.right.insert(data)
        else:
            self.data = data

    def lookup(self, data, parent=None):

        if data < self.data:
            if self.left is None:
                return None, None
            return self.left.lookup(data, self)
        elif data > self.data:
            if self.right is None:
               return None, None
            return self.right.lookup(data, self)
        else:
            return self, parent

    def delete(self, data):

        node, parent = self.lookup(data)
        if node is not None:
            children_count = node.children_count()
            if children_count == 0:

                if parent:
                    if parent.left is node:
                        parent.left = None
                    else:
                        parent.right = None
                else:
                    self.data = None
            elif children_count == 1:

                if node.left:
                    n = node.left
                else:
                    n = node.right
                if parent:
                    if parent.left is node:
                        parent.left = n
                    else:
                        parent.right = n
                else:
                    self.left = n.left
                    self.right = n.right
                    self.data = n.data
            else:

                parent = node
                successor = node.right
                while successor.left:
                     parent = successor
                     successor = successor.left

                node.data = successor.data

                if parent.left == successor:
                    parent.left = successor.right
                else:
                    parent.right = successor.right

    def compare_trees(self, node):

        if node is None:
            return False
        if self.data != node.data:
            return False
        res = True
        if self.left is None:
            if node.left:
                return False
        else:
            res = self.left.compare_trees(node.left)
        if res is False:
            return False
        if self.right is None:
            if node.right:
                return False
        else:
            res = self.right.compare_trees(node.right)
        return res

    def print_tree(self):

        if self.left:
            self.left.print_tree()
        print(self.data, end=" ")
        if self.right:
            self.right.print_tree()

    def height(self, root):
        if root is None:
            return 0
        else:
            return max(self.height(root.left), self.height(root.right)) + 1



random.seed(3)



bst = Node(random.randint(1,1000)) 
for i in range(1,80000,1):
    bst.insert(random.randint(1,1000))

print(bst.height(bst))
```

Comment: Are you *sure* it's wrong? I don't see why the height should necessarily be close to N, even before it's balanced.

Comment: This is the expected answer of an exercise I have been given as homework. I know the height *can* be much smaller than N but it all depends on the order of wich the elements are inserted in the tree structure. Having tested it for many cases and always getting a relatively small number as a result, i think I have made a mistake somewhere in either my code or logic.

Comment: Getting a height "close" to N is actually pretty improbable. It would require that the random string of numbers you populate the list with to be close to sorted already.

Comment: That is true. But getting a tree height of 41 while inputting 80000 random integers from 1 to 1000000000000 is equally unlikely, isn't it? Am I missing something?

Comment: Is maybe something wrong with the insert function then?

Comment: Looking at the discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861393/average-height-of-a-binary-search-tree), especially the approximation equation given in Robert Ollington's answer, that sounds like a reasonable result.

Comment: Keep in mind that a filled 41-level tree holds 2.2 trillion nodes. Your 80000 entries take up a tiny, tiny percentage of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting low answer because you are always inserting number from 1 to 1000 only so the numbers existing are always remains same and you are thinking you are inserting 1,80000 numbers but actually because of generating randomly the same numbers from 1 to 1000 you are actually inserting just 1000 values from 1 to 1000 maximum.

**Wrong Code**

```
bst = Node(random.randint(1,1000)) 
for i in range(1,80000,1):
    bst.insert(random.randint(1,1000))

print(bst.height(bst))
```

**Modification**

```
bst = Node(random.randint(1,80000)) 
for i in range(1,80000,1):
    bst.insert(random.randint(1,80000))

print(bst.height(bst))
```

Your code is working fine you can execute below code and check it with the image below
[image]

```
bst = Node(7)
list1 = [3,11,1,5,9,13,4,6,8,12,14,8.5]
for i in list1:
    bst.insert(i)
print(bst.height(bst))
bst.print_tree()
```

**Ouput**

```
5
1 3 4 5 6 7 8 8.5 9 11 12 13 14
```

Comment: see this answer it might help you

Comment: Thank you for the analytical answer! After I tried what you suggested above (the modification) as well as some much bigger numbers but I still get a relatively small answer for the height as it is always around 40 even for 80000 or 100000. Is this actually a normal number? Does the problem occur in bigger numbers only, if there is one?

Comment: yes that is a normal height of a binary search tree, you should get **log2 N (minimum)** and upto **N (maximum)** of height for binary search tree .. in your case it is **log2 (80,000)** to **80,000** i.e., ~16 to 80,000 ... where you are getting around 40 that means your tree is well formed and it is normal

Comment: Thank you very much, this answered all my questions!

Answer (score 0):

You should declare as sorted array to get maximum height for binary search tree.
but this may not work for larger numbers as 1000 or 10,000 . It will work fine for 500 elements because of your recursion for insertion may exceed the maximum recursion depth in python

**UPTO 500**

```
bst = Node(0)
list1 = list(range(1,500,1))
for i in list1:
    bst.insert(i)
print(bst.height(bst))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
499
```

**1000 elements**

```
bst = Node(0)
list1 = list(range(1,500,1))
for i in list1:
    bst.insert(i)
print(bst.height(bst))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
self.right.insert(data)
self.right = Node(data)

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```